# delphi: ROW-00025: Invalid RowSetHandle when executing a query on an oracle db

Tags: oracle, delphi, 64-bit, ado, oledbconnection

I've created a small 64-Bit application and I want to execute a simple query

```
select field1, field2 from table where field1 = 'xyz' order by 1
```

on an oracle db.

I am using:

- Windows 10
- Oracle Database 11g Client (x64)
- Delphi 10.1.2 Berlin
- TADOQuery with the connection string:

  ```
  Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=XYZ;User ID=XYZ;DataSource=XYZ;Persist Security Info=True
  ```

When executing the query I get the error:

> ROW-00025: Invalid RowSetHandle

I have never seen any error like this before.
Do you have any ideas? If you need more information, let me know in the comments below.

Comment: Hi may I ask why you're not using dbExpress or FireDAC? These are the preferred methods to connect to oracle lately.

Comment: You could debug it faster by windows cmd using sqlplus. Try connection and basic sql like SELECT * FROM table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions and comments. Meanwhile we found a solution...

We need to set the `CursorLocation` from the `ADOQuery` from `clUseServer` to `clUseClient`. With this change our query works. I guess our oracle server has some issues.

Answer (score -2):

can you try in this way,

select field1, field2 from table where field1 = 'xyz' and rownum=1;